# TwitterからユーザIDとハッシュタグを指定してランダムにツイートを取得する方法はありますか？

Tags: android, twitter

指定したユーザのツイートから特定のハッシュタグがついてツイートをランダムで一件だけ取得する方法を探しています。

[TwitterのREST APIのドキュメント](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)を見ましたが、これを実現できそうなAPIは無さそうでした。
TwitterのAPIを使わなくとも、何がいい方法があればお願いします。

ちなみに上記を利用してAndroidアプリの作成を考えています。

Answer (score 1):

検索API (`search/tweets`)に `from:jack #ImWithKap` のようなscreen nameとハッシュタグを含めた検索クエリを投げ、結果からランダムに選択することで実現は可能かと思います。

ただし、

- 検索APIのサンプル対象は近傍1週間
- 一度のリクエストで取得できる件数は100件まで

などといった制約があるので注意が必要です。
(公式アプリのCK専用のエンドポイントでは前者の制約が回避できますがここでは割愛します)

[The Search API — Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

(既に登録されていることを前提にtwilog等の外部ログサービスの検索をスクレイピングしたりすることも可能かもしれませんが、おすすめはしません。)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。"検索APIのサンプル対象は近傍1週間"と言う制限はuntilを設定した場合のみでしょうか？ なんか実現可能な気がしてきました

Comment: 1週間の制約は「現在から」だったはずです……(多少の誤差はありますが1週間を超えるuntilを設定するとそもそも結果が空になりますよね)

Comment: [apigee.com](https://apigee.com/console/twitter)でAPI叩いてみましたが、一応１週間前のツイートも取得できました。しかし、やっぱりランダムじゃないですね。。。ん〜難しそうですね

Comment: ランダム、という点では自分で乱数かけて選ぶしかないですよね……